# Use the same GraphQL schema using different endpoints using Apollo

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, graphql-tools

**Context**

Today I have a simple GraphQL stitching server that unify two graphql applications into a single graphql endpoint

**AS IS**

It works introspecting each service (app 1 & app 2) and building an `ApolloLink` assigning a host url to each app with `apollo-upload-client` and `apollo-link-http`.

[image]

After this I Merge both schemas using `mergeSchemas` from `graphql-tools` libray.

**Problem**

Now I have to consume another service that is equal to app 1 but it uses another database, consequently another url, but when i instantiate the **app 1** apollo-link using a diferente host the mergeSchemas ignores it and the final stitched schema continue as it initial state.

How to use the same schema with different URL's?

**TO BE**

I want to stitch 2 similar schemas using different url's 
[image]

**UPDATE**

I've instantiate the schemas multiple times using different urls for each one, but this gave me duplicate schemas. whitch solves my problem but i think that there are better solutions to keep with the same schema and switch hosts by a header, for example.

[image]

Is there any better solution to keep just with 2 schemas?

Comment: If there is no parameter/identifier to switch between same schemas, what's the point of stitching? Wouldn't it become a load balancing problem?

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı, no, because I have app 1 running in different environments with different data, and sometimes from my stitching i want to access  app1 in http://europe.service1.com/graphql and sometimes from http://asia.service1.com/graphql.

Comment: in that case, there is a business logic to access different data source. Which is not part of your gql schemas, hence the issue. In that case you can only differentiate by a parameter, header or schema. I hope someone answers with a better solution :D